# Can't convert video to grayscale

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to convert a video from my camera feed, which has low fps to gray. I have successfully fetched the video now I want to convert it to grayscale.

I've tried basic opencv operations and it isn't working. I get a video file when I open it there is no video.

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
print(fourcc)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('grey.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (800,600))
while True:    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    cv2.imshow('frame1',frame)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that you camera is not RGB, most webcams are YUV, you need to determine the format of your camera feed so you pass the correct colour conversion enum

Comment: and how can i find that?

Comment: You're supposed to either set your camera up or get the capabilities: `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT)` which will return the current format, you need to do more research

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `isColor` flag in `cv2.VideoWriter`. Currently the video writer setting is set to color instead of gray scale. You're incorrectly attempting to save a 3-channel color image (OpenCV default is BGR) as a gray scale image.

Change

`out = cv2.VideoWriter('grey.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (800,600))`

to

`out = cv2.VideoWriter('grey.avi',fourcc, 30.0, (800,600), isColor=False)`

Also your overall goal seems to capture video from a stream/camera feed and save the captured video in gray scale format. Here's an 'all in one' widget that reads frames from a camera stream link (RTSP), converts each frame to gray scale, and saves it as a video. Change `video_src` to your camera stream link.

[image: RTSP video stream to grayscale video]

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class VideoToGrayscaleWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        # Create a VideoCapture object
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)

        # Default resolutions of the frame are obtained (system dependent)
        self.frame_width = int(self.capture.get(3))
        self.frame_height = int(self.capture.get(4))

        # Set up codec and output video settings
        self.codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
        self.output_video = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', self.codec, 30, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height), isColor=False)

        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()

    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                (self.status, self.frame) = self.capture.read()

    def show_frame(self):
        # Convert to grayscale and display frames
        if self.status:
            self.gray = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            cv2.imshow('grayscale frame', self.gray)

        # Press 'q' on keyboard to stop recording
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord('q'):
            self.capture.release()
            self.output_video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            exit(1)

    def save_frame(self):
        # Save grayscale frame into video output file
        self.output_video.write(self.gray)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    video_src = 'Your video stream link!'
    video_stream_widget = VideoToGrayscaleWidget(video_src)
    while True:
        try:
            video_stream_widget.show_frame()
            video_stream_widget.save_frame()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, I did change the color flag, it gives me an empty video. Sorry.

Comment: Interesting, try change `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')` to `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')`. I wasn't able to get it to work with the former. Also ensure your OpenCV version is up to date with `pip install --upgrade opencv-python`.